# Grant required permissions for android app

Tags: android, android-camera, android-permissions

The application is a cam scanner for mobile phones, the application perfectly scans documents and saves and shares them, but when I want to activate the qr reader or qr generator or even open an image from the gallery I get the following error

"you have forcefully denied some of the required permissions for this action. please open setting, go to permissions and allow them"

the application has allowed camera permission to scan the qr code and all the permissions that the application requests have been allowed but even so it does not allow me to use the qr reade and qr generator or open images from the gallery.

here is my manifest. I would really appreciate your help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.Pdf.scanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CamScanner"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            tools:replace="android:authorities,android:exported">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
                tools:replace="android:resource" />
        </provider>

        <activity
            android:name="com.scanlibrary.ScanActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.BaseActivity"
            android:exported="true"

            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.LangSupportBaseActivity"
            android:exported="false"/>
        <activity android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.LanguageSelectionActivity"
            android:exported="false"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:resizeableActivity="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.MultiEditActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.ScannerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/uCropStyle" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.IDCardPreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.CropDocumentActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.CurrentFilterActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.SavedDocumentActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.DocumentEditorActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.SavedEditDocumentActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.SavedDocumentPreviewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.NoteActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.ImageToTextActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.GroupDocumentActivity"
            android:exported="true"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.PDFViewerActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.QRGenerateActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.QRReaderActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.Pdf.scanner.activity.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <meta-data
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
        <meta-data
            android:exported="true"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="@string/admob_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.nguyenhoanglam.imagepicker.ui.imagepicker.ImagePickerActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/imagepicker_ImagePickerTheme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.nguyenhoanglam.imagepicker.ui.camera.CameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="unspecified"
            android:theme="@style/imagepicker_CameraTheme"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:replace="android:screenOrientation" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.FCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
```

I would like your help to be able to use the qr reader, qr generator and open images from the gallery.

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: `"you have forcefully denied some of the required permissions for this action. please open setting, go to permissions and allow them"` We will fire this programmer not mentioning which permissions.

Comment: used device is android 13 version.
permission denied i guess is allow camera permission to scan the qr code and open galery images

Comment: `all the permissions that the application requests have been allowed` Dont think so. On an Android 13 device requesting READ and WRITE permission at runtime will fail. Please retry and confirm.

Comment: `and open galery images ` ? How are you trying to 'open' a gallery image?

Comment: Maybe I expressed myself wrong, the application only requests the camera permission and it is granted. and the mentioned error appears when I try to open the qr reader, qr generator and images from the gallery

Comment: `I try to open the qr reader, qr generator and images from the gallery` Sorry,l have no idea what you do or try to do. And i already did ask:  How are you trying to 'open' a gallery image? 
`But you did not elaborate.